# Mocked OkHttpClient

Tags: android, unit-testing, okhttp

just wanted to mock the OkHttpClient for testing purposes with Mockito. Sadly OkHttpClient is a final class which isn't supported by Mockito. Is there any other possibility to do the mocking, what do you guys do in there cicrumstaces?

Best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HttpURLConnection API that OkHttp 1.x uses doesn't really lend itself to mocking. We're working on a new API for OkHttp 2 that will fit this use case better.

In the interim you may want to look at OkHttp's MockWebServer, which uses a real, in-process HTTP server.

Comment: Do you have an example for the MockWebServer?

Comment: https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/mockwebserver/src/test/java/com/squareup/okhttp/mockwebserver/MockWebServerTest.java#L157